# How to mark a special place on google map api on google initial load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I am trying to get a place name from the user and mark it on the google map, on initial map load. So what I do is I get the place name and zoom value using session from another page, and place it in map attributes. The zoom part works ok, but the marking part does not work, I have worked on it a lot and tried different things, but this is my latest version of the code and it shows no marking on the map, and there is no error as well.

This is my code:

```
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

var myStyles =[
    {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
              { visibility: "off" }
        ]
    }
]; 

    function initialize() {

        var zm = <%= Session["value2"]%>;
        var ft= '<%= Request.QueryString["value"] %>';



        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

                    center: latlng2,
                    zoom: zm,
                    styles: myStyles
                });

                var request2 = {
                    location: latlng2,
                    radius: 2000,
                    types: [ft]
                };
                service.nearbySearch(request2, callback);
            });
}


            function callback(results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                        createMarker(results[i],icon);

                    }
                }
            }


            function createMarker(place,icon) {
                var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: place.geometry.location,
                    icon: icon,
                    visible:true  

                });




                markersArray.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent("<b>Name:</b>"+place.name+"<br><b>Address:</b>"+place.vicinity);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });

            }
```

I will be so thankful if you help me.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  I doubt the geolocation is required (unless the issue is that it isn't working).

Answer (score 1):

the console clearly says:

```
TypeError: service.nearbysearch is not a function
```

the function is actually `nearbySearch` not `nearbysearch` as per `GOOGLE MAPS API DOCUMENTAION`

Comment: Fixed it, the error is gone, but still does not mark any place.

Comment: try testing out if your call back status is `OK`, you can do that by having an `else` for your `if control`, log anything in the else part to see if its not `OK`